# counting of figures does not work in plantuml extension (asciidoctor-diagram)

Tags: asciidoctor, plantuml

I work with maven

```
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-RC.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0-beta.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoctorj-diagram</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.18</version>

                   <require>asciidoctor-diagram</require>
                </requires>
```

the following situation:

```
:desc-image1: description image 1
[id="image1",reftext="{figure-caption} {counter:figures}"]
.{desc-image1}
image::image1.png[align="center"]

:desc-plantuml: description plantuml
[id="plantuml",reftext="{figure-caption} {counter:figures}"]
.{figure-caption} {figures}: {desc-plantuml}
plantuml::images/plantuml.puml[align="center"]

:desc-image2: description image 2
[id="image2",reftext="{figure-caption} {counter:figures}"]
.{desc-image2}
image::image2.png[align="center"]
```

please observe, I added {figure-caption} {figures}: in the plantuml part

So I have two problems (The images are correct!):
a wrong numbering of the image2 in the text (html and pdf)

```
Figure 2: description image 2 expected Figure 3: description image 2
```

The Caption and the number is not generated automatically at plantuml . Why?

```
Figure 1: description image 1
description plantuml             expected    Figure 2: description plantuml
Figure 2: description image 2   expected    Figure 3: description image 2
```

is the problem located in line 609 of parser.rb the reason in 2.0.0.RC1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asciidoctor.maven.plugin.version>2.0.0-RC.1</asciidoctor.maven.plugin.version>
<asciidoctorj.pdf.version>1.5.0-beta.**7**</asciidoctorj.pdf.version>
**<asciidoctorj.version>2.1.0</asciidoctorj.version>**
<asciidoctor.diagram.version>1.5.18</asciidoctor.diagram.version>
```

using this versions solves the problem